# getting records of one and only one type

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I was sitting several hours for trying to solve on specific problem but I couldn't get it. Finally, I decided to post it here. Here are some records,

```
╔════════╦════════════╦═════════╦══════════════════╗
║ AUTOID ║ PERSONNAME ║ FLOWER  ║ Other columns... ║
╠════════╬════════════╬═════════╬══════════════════╣
║      1 ║ Alex       ║ Rose    ║                  ║
║      2 ║ Rene       ║ Rose    ║                  ║
║      3 ║ Rene       ║ Jasmin  ║                  ║
║      4 ║ Darwin     ║ Rose    ║                  ║
║      5 ║ Alex       ║ Rose    ║                  ║
║      6 ║ Darwin     ║ Jasmin  ║                  ║
║      7 ║ Alex       ║ Rose    ║                  ║
║      8 ║ Rene       ║ Jasmin  ║                  ║
║      9 ║ Hello      ║ World   ║                  ║
║     10 ║ Hello      ║ World   ║                  ║
╚════════╩════════════╩═════════╩══════════════════╝
```

How can I get this result, **the person who has only one type of flower on all his/her records**.

```
╔════════════╦════════════╗
║ PERSONNAME ║ FLOWERNAME ║
╠════════════╬════════════╣
║ Alex       ║ Rose       ║
║ Hello      ║ World      ║
╚════════════╩════════════╝
```

the best one I tried was this query below, and still not working.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t1.PersonName, t1.Flower
FROM    TableName t1 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  personname, COUNT(DISTINCT flower) totals
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY personname, Flower
        )  t2 ON t1.personname = t2.personname and
                    t2.totals = 1
```

Any Idea?

Comment: what's the logic? why only those two records?

Comment: So what is the logic in getting that result?

Comment: @fthiella because each person have only one type of flower for all of the records.

Comment: @JeggarVance your query is almost correct, you can just `GROUP BY personname` instead of `GROUP BY personname, Flower`

Comment: @fthiella wow thanks! can you post that as an answer so I can give you  credit? I can voteup now. But JW. has an interesting answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `GROUP BY` clause, `HAVING` clause and `COUNT()` on this problem, *no need to join on a subquery*

```
SELECT  PersonName, MAX(Flower) flowerName
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY PersonName
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT Flower) = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/584e0/1)

Answer (score 0):

or, because there's always more than one way to skin a cat...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM tablename x
  LEFT
  JOIN tablename y
    ON y.personname = x.personname
   AND ((y.flower <> x.flower)
    OR  (y.flower = x.flower AND y.autoid < x.autoid))
 WHERE y.autoid IS NULL;
```