# Mysql - can't pass variable into subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Here is my query:

```
SELECT user.*, @UserID:=user.uid,
    (SELECT count(c1) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS c1 FROM user_group
    WHERE user_group.uid=@UserID
    GROUP BY user_group.uid
) x1) AS x2

FROM user
```

Problem is that `@UserID` in not passed to sub-query

Comment: The innermost query is evaluated and executed first. Thus its value is not known yet. Chicken and egg problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using `JOIN`? I think the result is the same as what you want. And I'm guessing that *you want to get the total number of group the user has*. Right?

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) totalCount,
        COALESCE(b.totalType, 0) totalType
FROM    user a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  uid, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount, 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT type) totalType
            FROM    user_Group 
            GROUP BY uid
        ) b ON a.uid = b.uid
```

Comment: Also when i have in GROUP BY type, uid   query return multiple rows which I want to count

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: uid  type;
2  V;
3  V;
8  V;
9  V;
2  P;
3  P;
7  P;
8  P;
9  P

Comment: and what's the result of that?

Comment: based on the example, this could be simply solved as `SELECT uid, COUNT(*) totalCount FROM tableName GROUP BY uid` .

Comment: but i need to know hop many types user has e.g. user 7 has just V type counter=1; user 3 has V & P counter = 2

Comment: you question seem to be getting more complicated. you have show me an example, *which is good*, but you didn't really tell me what you are really asking, can you give sample records with desired result like  on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651761/getting-records-of-one-and-only-one-type/14651790#14651790 don't mind the borders.

Answer (score 4):

Why to pass the variable there? Directly use the outer table reference like this.

```
SELECT user.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS c1 FROM user_group
WHERE user_group.uid=user.uid
GROUP BY user_group.uid) AS GroupCount
FROM user;
```

Comment: Unknown column 'u.uid' in 'where clause'

Comment: I think you are looking for number of groups the user is present in. For that I edited the query. Have a look.